# Is there a way to modify the solid of revolution integral to allow for solids of increasing and decreasing radius?

Tags: calculus, geometry, parametric, solid-of-revolution

I am doing a project on tori as they relate to pool floaties and the volume of a normal torus can be calculated by the solids of revolution integral on a circle, Is there a way to modify the integral so that the radius of the circle changes as it is rotated? therefore allowing me to calculate the volume of this shape [modified torus where radius of cross section increases and decreases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnKwt.png)

defined by parametric equations

$F_x (s,t)= (R + r (|(|t/π|-1)|+1)\cos⁡(s)) \cos⁡(t)$

$F_y (s,t)= (R + r (|(|t/π|-1)|+1)  \cos⁡(s) )  \sin⁡(t)$

$F_z (s,t)= r (|(|t/π|-1)|+1)  \sin(s)$

Also, does Pappus's centroid theorem apply to this shape?

It is my first question and I don't believe there are any repeats of this.

Comment: If each radial section is a circle, is your question is if volume can be found by $ ∫Adt/ \pi ∗2π∗(R−r/2) ?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's try to simplify where we can.

You can divide your "floaty" in two parts on each side of a vertical plane of symmetry, so that one part is the mirror image of the other. Compute the volume of one part and multiply by $2.$

For one half, it looks like you can let $t$ range from $0$ to $\pi.$
Then $\lvert t/\pi\rvert = t/\pi \leq 1,$
therefore $\lvert t/\pi\rvert - 1 \leq 0,$
therefore $\lvert(\lvert t/\pi\rvert - 1)\rvert = 1 - \lvert t/\pi\rvert = 1 - t/\pi,$
therefore $\lvert(\lvert t/\pi\rvert - 1)\rvert + 1 = 2 - t/\pi.$
That simplifies your parameterization:
\begin{align}
F_x (s,t) &= (R + (2 - t/\pi) r \cos(s)) \cos(t), \\
F_y (s,t) &= (R + (2 - t/\pi) r \cos(s)) \sin(t), \\
F_z (s,t) &= (2 - t/\pi) r \sin(s).
\end{align}

But to represent points inside the floaty, not just on its outer skin, we need a third parameter. Let
\begin{align}
F_x (s,t,u) &= (R + (2 - t/\pi) ru \cos(s)) \cos(t), \\
F_y (s,t,u) &= (R + (2 - t/\pi) ru \cos(s)) \sin(t), \\
F_z (s,t,u) &= (2 - t/\pi) ru \sin(s),
\end{align}
that is, $u$ is the relative distance from the circle of radius $R$ inside the floaty, ranging from $0$ on that circle to $1$ on the outer surface of the floaty.

This is a transformation from $\mathbb R^3$ (with coordinates $s,t,u$)
to $\mathbb R^3$ (with coordinates $x,y,z$) whose Jacobian is
$$
J = - (2 - t/\pi)^2 r^2 R u - (2 - t/\pi)^3 r^3 u^2 \cos(s),
$$
with absolute value
$$
\lvert J\rvert = (2 - t/\pi)^2 r^2 u \left(R + (2 - t/\pi) r u \cos(s)\right)
$$

An intuitive derivation of this is that when we integrate over the three parameters
$s,$ $t,$ and $u$ to find the volume,
a change of $\mathrm ds$ in $s$ is a distance of $(2 - t/\pi) ru\,\mathrm ds,$
a change of $\mathrm dt$ in $t$ is a distance of
$(R + (2 - t/\pi) ru\cos(s))\,\mathrm dt,$
and a change of $\mathrm du$ in $u$ is a distance of $(2 - t/\pi) r\,\mathrm du.$
The product of these three is the "volume element",
$\lvert J\rvert \,\mathrm ds \,\mathrm dt \,\mathrm du,$
and you can work out that
$(2 - t/\pi) ru \times (R + (2 - t/\pi) ru\cos(s)) \times (2 - t/\pi) r$
equals $\lvert J\rvert$ in the equation above.

For the volume of half the floaty, $s$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$ (all the way around the circular cross-section of the tube), $t$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$, and $u$ goes from $0$ to $1,$ so we want to integrate
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \int_0^1
\left((2 - t/\pi)^2 r^2 u \left(R + (2 - t/\pi) r u \cos(s)\right)\right)
 \,\mathrm du \,\mathrm dt \,\mathrm ds.
$$

---

Obviously Pappus's centroid theorem cannot be applied here since the circular cross section keeps chanaging; Pappus assumes you have a uniform cross section throughout the figure. But the form of the integral does suggest something analogous to Pappus's centroid theorem for volume: namely, the cross-sections of the volume perpendicular to the circle $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$ all have centroids on that circle, and we can "straighten out" the circle while keeping all those cross-sections perpendicular to the line through their centroids
without changing the volume of the region.
We end up transforming one half of the floaty into a circular frustum
with bases $2r$ and $r$ and height $\pi R$ (the length of half the circle).
The difference between this and Pappus's theorem is that the formula from Pappus's theorem assumes that the "straightened-out" volume is a cylinder, which has a simpler volume formula than the frustum.

Comment: Is there a name for solids of revolution like the torus I found? trying to think of a name for it in my paper but can't find any similar shapes online, its not a Duplin cyclide but it's very similar looking.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the method you asked for, but I think a general formula for the volume enclosed by a parametric surface might be easier than constructing a surface of revolution approach. Given that [Gauss's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Mathematical_statement) states for a smooth vector field $\vec{F}$ we have
$\newcommand{\oiint}{{\subset\!\supset}\llap{\iint}}$
$$
\iiint_V \nabla\cdot\vec{F} \, \mathrm{d}V = \oiint_S \left(\vec{F}\cdot\hat{n}\right)\, \mathrm{d}S \tag{1}
$$
Also, if the surface $S$ is parametrized by a curve $\vec{r}:T\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \to\mathbb{R}^3$ given as $\vec{r}(s,t) =(r_x(s,t), r_y(s,t), r_z(s,t))$ then
$$
\oiint_S \left(\vec{F}\cdot\hat{n}\right)\, \mathrm{d}S = \iint_{T} \vec{F}\left(\vec{r}(s,t)\right) \cdot\left(\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial t}\right)\, \mathrm{d}s\,\mathrm{d}t \tag{2}
$$
Now, if we choose a vector field $\vec{F}$ such that $\nabla\cdot\vec{F} =1$ then the LHS of $(1)$ is just the volume $V = \iiint_V \mathrm{d}V$. So taking $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=(0,0,z)$ its divergence is indeed $1$, so combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ with this specific vector field we get
$$
V = \iint_{T} \left(0,0,r_z(s,t)\right) \cdot\left(\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial t}\right)\, \mathrm{d}s\,\mathrm{d}t =  \boxed{\iint_{T} r_z\left(  \frac{\partial r_x}{\partial s}\frac{\partial r_y}{\partial t} -\frac{\partial r_y}{\partial s}\frac{\partial r_x}{\partial t} \right)\, \mathrm{d}s\,\mathrm{d}t}
$$
as an integral for the enclosed volume.